# Corrected Code for Loading Data from CSV into Surprise Dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/surprise/reader.py in parse_line(self, line)
    100             else:
--> 101                 uid, iid, r = (line[i].strip() for i in self.indexes)
    102                 timestamp = None

6 frames
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/surprise/reader.py in parse_line(self, line)
    103 
    104         except IndexError:
--> 105             raise ValueError(
    106                 "Impossible to parse line. Check the line_format" " and sep parameters."
    107             )

ValueError: Impossible to parse line. Check the line_format and sep parameters.
```

I am trying to read the dataset by using this code :

```
from surprise import Dataset, Reader

# Specify the path to your dataset
file_path = '/content/ratings.csv'

# Define the reader with the appropriate format
reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating', sep='\t', rating_scale=(1, 5))

# Load data from the CSV file using Dataset.load_from_file
data = Dataset.load_from_file(file_path, reader=reader)
```

Comment: Did you try what the error says? Are you sure the line separator is a tab? Does the CSV file contain those exact columns, in that order, not more or less or using different names?

Comment: Evidently your `Reader` arguments don't match the actual format of the `ratings.csv` file. If you provide a minimal sample `ratings.csv` which reproduces the error, we can tell you exactly what the difference is.

Comment: We can't guess what `ratings.csv` contains. Post the first 2-3 lines at least. You can also try loading the file into a Pandas dataframe and inspect it.  Perhaps some lines are truncated or have extra fields. Perhaps the separator isn't a tab at all. Or the file is fixed-width instead of tab separated